# Get all session cookies in PHP

Tags: session-cookies, php

I have multiple cookies having scope for one session. Now I want to get all those cookies having expiry of one session.

I searched for it, I found function `session_get_cookie_params` that gives information of default and only PHP's session cookie name PHPSESSID.

Problem is I want to get all session cookies and don't know names of cookies.

Is this possible to get all cookies having scope of session?

Thanks,

**Edit**:

Here is a usecase:

Save all cookies in database except those will expire after current session.
There may be many cookies those will expire at the end of session. Basically I need to know which cookie will expire at the end of current session.

Comment: You can retrieve the full list of cookies just using the $_COOKIE variable, if that is what you're asking for. (Try to var_dump it)

Comment: @Jerska I can get list of all cookies. How would I know that this(these) specific cookie(s) is session cookie(s)?

Comment: `session_get_cookie_params` function receives no params.http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php

Comment: Can you expand your question? Having multiple cookies on the same client with different session identifiers makes no sense.